# pkg-config can not find opencv libraries

Tags: linux, opencv, opencv3.0, archlinux, pkg-config

I have opencv4 installed on my arch linux. I have a project that consist pkg-config command:

```
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

But it gives this error:

> opencv development package not found

The project developed a computer that uses **opencv 3.2**. So i installed **opencv3-opt**(exact version 3.4.19) package from AUR. Now I can call **pkg-config** with **opencv3** and **opencv4** arguments. But I need to call it with directly **opencv** argument. What should i do for that?

Comment: No, its regular pc.

Comment: how did you install opencv ? and is this qt you are trying to link your opencv library

Comment: Yes its qt. i installed opencv4 from official repo, opencv3-opt from aur. I need opencv 3 to run codes properly because some structers used in codes does not included in opencv4.

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PsxwpJnWD0&t=86s) may help about linking opencv to qt

Comment: My problem is not linking qt with opencv

Comment: why not change the makefile to use opencv3?